# ¿Como ingresar los valores de una columna de una tabla de SQL SERVER a una tabla en postgres?

Tags: python, sql-server, base-de-datos, django, postgresql

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto en donde debo implementar valores consultados en un sp de SQL SERVER e implementarlos en una tabla en Postgres utilizando Python pero mi consulta es, ¿Es posible poder pasar esos valores de distintos formatos de sql usando python? y ¿Las claves foraneas aun siguen vigentes si se menciona el sp de SQL SERVER en python?

Estoy trabajando con 4 tablas y un procedimiento:
antecedente_general -> asc_id como clave primaria,
beneficio -> tabla que se necesita poblar(con asc_id como foranea),
SP-> consulta los valores de varias tablas en donde una de esas tablas(ASIGNACION) esta relacionada con la tabla ALUMNO(con clave foranea alu_rut en ASIGNACION).

se necesita asociar alu_rut de la tabla ASIGNACION(foranea) de SQL SERVER con asc_rut de la tabla antecedente_general de Postgres para poder obtener el asc_id de la tabla beneficio .

he probado varias cosas como subqueris, clases y django pero nada, alguien sabrá?

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Hay varias preguntas dentro de tu pregunta, sin código para ver y sin idea de cuáles son los detalles de las tablas, los datos de prueba y el resultado esperado en la tabla destino. Como no hay una forma clara de responder, posiblemente termine cerrada a menos que vayas a [edit] y aclares cuál es el problema a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), incluyas el código que intentas usar y el error o errores/problemas que encuentras al correrlo.

Comment: Uno diría que sí, se puede hacer lo que quieres. Dices que has probado "pero nada". Es la peor forma de describir un error. Sé específico. Imagina que lees este problema de alguien más e intentas responder. Sólo estaríás adivinando y de eso no se trata. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Lectura altamente recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.